# Preservation of Positive-Definiteness from Small Perturbations

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, perturbation-theory

Let $A$ with real positive entries be a Hermitian positive definite matrix. I'm wondering if one perturbs $A$, e.g., $\hat{A}=A+\Delta A$, would the matrix still be positive definite? I'm told this is particularly true so long as the perturbation satisfies the condition number bound
$$\frac{\|\Delta A\|}{\|A\|} < \frac{1}{K(A)},$$
where $K(A)$ is the condition number $K(A)=\|A^{-1}\|\|A\|$ (all in the Frobenius norm). I'm stuck figuring out how to prove this. Since $A$ is positive definite, it has a unique Cholesky decomposition $A=LL^*$ and so $\hat A=LL^*+\Delta A$. But this leads me nowhere in proving that $\hat A$ too has unique Cholesky decomposition dependent on the condition number.

Comment: I've asked a very similar question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2451950/259085), where I'm looking for results when $\Delta A$ isn't symmetric (as the answer below assumes). Please do let me know if you have found out anything about this case. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition you've given will follow from the weaker bound
$$
\|\Delta A\|_2 < \|A^{-1}\|^{-1}_2
$$
where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is the induced norm from the Euclidean metric.

We can argue as follows. For $t > 0$ sufficiently small, $A_t = A + t \Delta A$ is going to be PD by some general considerations (this is a good exercise). Assume that $\Delta A$ obeys the bound given, and for the sake of contradiction, assume that for some $t \leq 1$, $A_t$ is not positive definite.

I claim that there is a $t' \leq 1$ such that $A_{t'}$ has a zero eigenvalue. Pursuing this, let $v \in \ker A_{t'}$ be a unit vector. Then $A_{t'} v = 0 = A v + t'\Delta A v$ and so
$$
\|A^{-1}\|_2^{-1} \leq \|A v\|_2 = t' \|\Delta A v\|_2 \leq \|\Delta A\|_2
$$
which is a contradiction.

Something to consider: this proof uses the connectedness of the set of PD matrices and the fact that when crossing continuously from the PD region to the SPD region, you necessary hit an SPD matrix with nontrivial kernel.

---

EDIT: Below is a simpler proof that doesn't use any topology.

Let $A$ be PD with eigenvalues $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \cdots \geq \sigma_n > 0$, counted with multiplicity. In particular, $\sigma_1 = \|A\|_2$ and $\sigma_n = \|A^{-1}\|_2^{-1}$. Writing the eigenvalues of the perturbation $\Delta A$ as $\{\eta_i\}_{1 \leq i \leq n}$ (with multiplicity) we have $\|\Delta A\|_2 = |\eta_j| = \max\{\eta_i \mid 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ for some $j$, which we take to be $1$ by re-indexing. Our condition ensures that $$|\eta_1| < \sigma_n$$.

Let $A' = A + \Delta A$ and assume that $(A'v, v) \leq 0$ for some unit vector $v$. We have
$$
(A v, v) \leq - (\Delta A v, v)
$$
Notice that $(Av, v) \geq \sigma_n$ and that $(\Delta Av, v) \leq |\eta_1|$ (this amounts to checking the Raleigh quotient and applying an appropriate minmax principle, if you like). Thus $\sigma_n \leq |\eta_1|$, which is a contradiction to our initial estimate.

Comment: Very interesting! I assume as a bare-bones proof, you could simply do this for $t=1$ rather than have $t$ in general to be $\leq 1$. The topological argument makes me curious what other analogous results you can try doing with them.

Comment: @Riem I realized that I could make the argument much simpler, using minmax principles. I feel better about the latter argument, since it really uses the self-adjoint theory, whereas the previous argument needed higher technology.

Comment: @A Blumenthal 
Maybe it's too late to ask a question .. lets try anyway. 
what are the assumptions on $\Delta A$ in order for the theorem to be valid? Can  $\Delta A$ be an arbitrary matrix (or , e.g., should it be diagonalizable in the same basis as $A$?). In my case I have a hermitian  positive semidefinite matrix A perturbed by another one B. the perturbation acts as a difference:  $\tilde{A}=A-B$ . does the theorem hold also in the positive semidefinite case?
thank you very much

Comment: Hah, good catch @the_elder. $\Delta A$ must be hermitian itself before this result can possibly be true.

Comment: @the_elder No, if $A$ is "genuinely" semi-definite then it possesses a zero eigenvalue, hence a nontrivial kernel, and so is therefore noninvertible. In particular, there exist arbitrarily small perturbations $B$ which 'push' $A$ towards having negative eigenvalues.

Comment: @the_elder It would be an interesting question (perhaps you should pose it!) to describe the geometry of the set of perturbations $B$ for which a given "strictly" positive semidefinite $A$ remains positive semidefinite.

Comment: @ABlumenthal W.r.t. your last comment, I'm looking for an answer to that question, but where $A$ is positive definite instead - did the_elder (or you) ever post that question?

Comment: Why the downvote?