# Preservation of positive definiteness from (non-symmetric) perturbations

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, perturbation-theory, symmetric-matrices

My question is identical to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/527605/259085). It roughly asks:

*If $A$ is symmetric (real and Hermitian) and positive definite ($x^TAx>0\;\forall x$) and $\hat{A}=A+\Delta A$ is a perturbed version of it, what condition(s) then ensure(s) that $\hat{A}$ is also positive-definite (but not necessarily symmetric)?*

The [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/527624/259085) to the mentioned question shows that if 
$$\|\Delta A\| < \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|},$$
where $\|\cdot\|$ is the induced norm from the Euclidean metric, then $\hat{A}$ is positive definite. However, this assumes that $\Delta A$ is symmetric.

**I'm looking for references giving such conditions, but where $\Delta A$ can be arbitrary.** I've looked at [Weyl's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl.27s_inequality_in_matrix_theory), but it again assumes that the perturbation is symmetric.

Comment: What is your definition of positive definite?  In many contexts, we can only say that $\hat A$ is positive definite if it's symmetric first.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you for pointing that out, see my edit.

Comment: your definition is *highly* unusual.  Typically, one says that a matrix $M$ is positive semidefinite if and only if $x^TMx$ is non-negative for all (real) vectors $x$, and positive definite if $x\neq 0 \implies x^TMx > 0$.  All positive definite matrices have the eigenvalues in the right half plane but the converse does not hold.  For instance, the matrix 
$$
\pmatrix{1&10\\0&1}
$$
would not be considered positive definite under the definition that I'm used to.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I don't know why, but I somehow hallucinated a problem with that definition in the non-symmetric case. That is definitely the definition I'll go forward with with this question. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: as it turns out, the definition I've given is equivalent to saying that $M$ is positive definite matrix if and only if the symmetric matrix $M + M^T$ is positive definite.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom What, if anything, does that mean for this problem? I can see that it means that $\hat{A}$ is PD iff $A+\frac{1}{2}(\Delta A+\Delta A^T)$ is PD, but how can I use this? Does this reduce the problem to when the perturbation is symmetric as well? I guess that if we set $\Delta A_S = \frac{1}{2}(\Delta A+\Delta A^T),$ then $\hat{A}$ is PD if $\|\Delta A_S\| < \frac{1}{\|A^{-1}\|}$?

Comment: That's exactly where I was going with that.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thank you very much, that was a very nice hint! Pretty amazing that it simply reduces to the case of a symmetric perturbation! Would you happen to know where I could find a written proof of the inequality provided by the answerer to the mentioned question? I'd like to cite it, so I don't have to provide a proof in my work. Either way, I'd accept the results of our discussion as an answer, if you are interested in posting it as such. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think I'll be posting an answer; thanks though.  Off the top of my head, Horn and Johnson's "Matrix Analysis" and "Topics in Matrix Analysis" are handy references, and I'd bet that one of them mentions the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

$x^T (A+\Delta A) x = x^T A x + x^T \Delta A x \ge\sigma_{min}(A)\|x\|^2-\sigma_{max}(\Delta A)\|x\|^2$, where$\sigma_{min}(M)$ is the smallest singular value of a matrix $M$ and $\sigma_{max}(M)$ is the largest singular value of a matrix $M$. So if $\sigma_{max}(\Delta A)< \sigma_{min}(A)$ we will have $x^T (A+\Delta A) x >0 \hspace{2pt} \forall x \ne 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you have a reference (or proof) for the stated inequality?